# Efecto degradado infinito css

Tags: html, css, css3

Estoy haciendo un efecto degradado en un background en CSS, pero tengo un problema cuando hago que el efecto sea un bucle.

```css
.container {
padding: 2rem;
}

.bg-pan-right {animation: 8s ease 0s infinite normal both running bg-pan-right;}
.bg-gradient-hor {background-image: linear-gradient(270deg,#cc6aa5,#3e91cc,#2dcca7); background-size: 600% 100%;}
@-webkit-keyframes bg-pan-right {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
}
@keyframes bg-pan-right {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container bg-pan-right bg-gradient-hor">
Efecto
</div>
```

Si ven el codigo el problema es que cuando el efecto termina y tiene que volver a iniciar y lo hace golpe, no hace un degradado entre el ultimo color y el primero y no se como resolverlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es el siguiente; de la forma en que configuras la animación ésta empieza en un color haciendo gradiente hasta otro sin retornar:

```
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
```

mostrándose de golpe el cambio del ultimo color con el primero.

Para evitar esto puedes hacer que la animación retorne al punto de partida de la siguiente forma:

```
   0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
   }
   50% {
      background-position: 100% 50%;
   }
   100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
   }
```

De ese modo el cambio de colores ya no se muestra de golpe.

Puedes ver el resultado en el siguiente código:

```css
.container {
padding: 2rem;
}

.bg-pan-right {animation: 8s ease 0s infinite normal both running bg-pan-right;}
.bg-gradient-hor {background-image: linear-gradient(270deg,#cc6aa5,#3e91cc,#2dcca7); background-size: 600% 100%;}
@-webkit-keyframes bg-pan-right {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }  
}
@keyframes bg-pan-right {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="container bg-pan-right bg-gradient-hor">
Efecto
</div>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: No habia tenido en cuenta el recorrido, vi en el manual que colocaba una linea del `50% {}`, pero no pense que era necesaria y al parecer lo es. Muchas gracias @the-breaker

Comment: @Qodde, de nada, buen fin de semana.

Comment: igual para ti...